# Delphi xe6 - Database Login (Informix)

Tags: delphi, authentication, database-connection, delphi-xe6

I'm making a login form on Delphi XE6 that reads an username and a password, and tries to make the connection to a database. Although I turn the LoginPrompt off, when it makes the connection it still pops up and only has the username written, the password it's blank.

I have the following code:

```
    SearchTab.DBCon := TSQLConnection.Create(self);
    SearchTab.DBCon.DriverName := 'Informix';
    SearchTab.DBCon.Params.Values['Hostname'] := 'XXXX';
    SearchTab.DBCon.Params.Values['DataBase'] := 'XXXX';
    SearchTab.DBCon.Params.Values['User_Name'] := UsernameEdit.Text;
    SearchTab.DBCon.Params.Values['Password']  := PwEdit.Text;

    SearchTab.DBCon.Connected:= True;
```

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: My problem was that the LoginPrompt showed although I had turned it up to false on the Object Inspector. The other problem was that in the Parans.Values the Username was being load to the login, but the password was blank, didn't had the value of the PwEdit.Text

Sorry, I read the post again and it is really unclear, my bad @user6426692

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume DBCon is VCL control placed on SearchTab Form ?
Just remove first line:

```
SearchTab.DBCon := TSQLConnection.Create(self);
```

or Set LoginPrompt to false in DBCon after You created it:

```
SearchTab.DBCon.LoginPrompt:=false;
```

You seem to use existing connection, but You create new, assigning default 
values
   ( including LoginPrompt) to DBCon.

Comment: I removed the Create line and worked. I didn't set the LoginPrompt to false like you advised because I had set it to false on the Object Inspetor.. I guess I needed that line too. Thank you!

Comment: That's why i used "OR" clause :) Either You create new connection and must set it's all values or use existing one, which allows You to change properties with object inspector. With Your first line You are assigning new default connection to existing one, thus "resetting" all values set by Object Inspector.